# Optimizing JavaScript autocorrect implementation

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I modified the jQuery Autocomplete implementation to generate autocorrect suggestions too. I used Levenshtein distance as the metric to decide closest matches.

My code runs at each keypress after the jQuery autocomplete does not have any more suggestions. Here's the code that I wrote:

```
// Returns edit distance between two strings
edit_distance : function(s1, s2) {
    // Auxiliary 2D array
    var arr = new Array(s1.length+1);
    for(var i=0 ; i<s1.length+1 ; i++)
        arr[i] = new Array(s2.length+1);

    // Algorithm
    for(var i=0 ; i<=s1.length ; i++)
        for(var j=0 ; j<=s2.length ; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 0;
    for(var i=0 ; i<=s1.length ; i++)
        arr[i][0] = i;
    for(var i=0 ; i<=s2.length ; i++)
        arr[0][i] = i;

    for(var i=1 ; i<=s1.length ; i++)
        for(var j=1 ; j<=s2.length ; j++)
            arr[i][j] = Math.min(arr[i-1][j-1] + (s1.charAt(i-1)==s2.charAt(j-1) ? 0 : 1), arr[i-1][j]+1, arr[i][j-1]+1);

    // Final answer
    return arr[s1.length][s2.length].toString(10);
},

// This is called at each keypress
auto_correct : function() {
    // Make object array for sorting both names and IDs in one go
    var objArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0 ; i<idArray.length ; i++) {
        objArray[i]      = new Object();
        objArray[i].id   = idArray[i];
        objArray[i].name = nameArray[i];
    }

    // Sort object array by edit distance
    var out = this;
    companyObjArray.sort (
        function(a,b) {
            var input = jQuery("#inputbox").val().toLowerCase();
            var d1    = a.name.toLowerCase();
            var d2    = b.name.toLowerCase();
            return out.editDistance(input,d1) - out.editDistance(input,d2);
        }
    );

    // Copy some closest matches in arrays that are shown by jQuery
    this.suggestions = new Array();
    this.data = new Array();
    for(var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) {
        this.suggestions.push(companyObjArray[i].name);
        this.data.push(companyObjArray[i].id);
    }
}
```

All names have IDs associated with them, so before sorting I'm just creating an object array out of them, and sorting the array.

Since the list to search from is in thousands, its slow. I found a data structure called a BK-tree, which can speed it up, but I'm can't implement it right now. I'm looking for optimization suggestions to speed this up. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT.** I decided to use [Sift3](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2013/06/sift3-gone-wild.html) as my string distance metric instead of Levenshein distance, it gives more meaningful results and is faster.

Comment: Move `var input = jQuery("#inputbox").val().toLowerCase();` three lines up, outside comparison function.

Comment: Actually, store the edit distance in objects. Recalculating it for each comparison seems wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things you can optimize here, but most of it boils down to this: Only do each of your 'heavier' calculations once. You are doing a lot of work on each keypress, in every sort comparison, etc., and caching those values will help a lot.

However, for a *significant added performance boost*, there is another, quite nifty optimization trick you can use. It is used by every major search engine, including on-site search engines on sites such as Amazon.com.

It takes advantage of the fact that you really don't need to sort the whole list, since all you're displaying are the top 10 or 12 items. Whether the rest of the thousands of list items are in the correct order doesn't matter in the least. So all you really have to keep track of while running through the list, are the top 10 or 12 items you've seen so far, which, as it turns out, is a *lot* faster than full sorting.

### Here's the idea in pseudocode:

1. The user types a character, creating a new search term
2. We define an empty `shortlist` array of length 12 (or however many suggestions we want)
3. Loop through the full list of words (we will call it the `dictionary`):

   1. Calculate the (Levenshtein) edit distance between the dictionary word and the search term
   2. If the distance is lower (better) than the current `threshold`, we:

      - Add the word to the top of the `shortlist`
      - Let the bottom word in the `shortlist` 'overflow' out of the list
      - Set our `threshold` distance to match the word now at the bottom of the `shortlist`
4. When the loop has finished, we have a `shortlist` containing some of the best words, but they are unsorted, so we sort just those 12 words, which will be really fast.

**One small caveat**: Depending on the dataset and the number of elements in your shortlist, the shortlist may differ *slightly* from the actual top elements, but this can be alleviated by increasing the shortlist size, e.g. to 50, and just removing the bottom 38 once the final sort is done.

### As for the actual code:

```
// Cache important elements and values
var $searchField = $('#searchField'),
    $results = $('#results'),
    numberOfSuggestions = 12,
    shortlistWindowSize = 50,
    shortlist,
    thresholdDistance;

// Do as little as possible in the keyboard event handler
$searchField.on('keyup', function(){
    shortlist = [];
    thresholdDistance = 100;

    // Run through the full dictionary just once,
    // storing just the best N we've seen so far
    for (var i=0; i<dictionarySize; i++) {
        var dist = edit_distance(this.value, dictionary[i]);
        if (dist < thresholdDistance) {
            shortlist.unshift({
                word: dictionary[i],
                distance: dist
            });
            if (shortlist.length > shortlistWindowSize) {
                shortlist.pop();
                thresholdDistance = shortlist[shortlistWindowSize-1].distance;
            }
        }
    }

    // Do a final sorting of just the top words
    shortlist.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.distance - b.distance;
    });


    // Finally, format and show the suggestions to the user
    $results.html('<p>' + $.map(shortlist, function(el){
        return '<span>[dist=' + el.distance + ']</span> ' + el.word;
    }).slice(0,numberOfSuggestions).join('</p><p>') + '</p>').show();
});
```

### Try the method out in this [12.000 word demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dF7Mz/3/)

Comment: Nice answer! But I think that initial threshold 100 is too high; it gets useless suggestions into the short list and that results in loss of more relevant suggestions. I'm getting somewhat less accurate results by this method, but they are very fast. I'm now experimenting with the threshold to get best possible results. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I didn't understand the point of changing `thresholdDistance` each time. After I implemented it, it generated poor results. Not updating it each time generated much better results.

Comment: The initial value is not meant to separate good from bad, it is just defined so it will be higher than every word in the dictionary. And if you don't update the `thresholdDistance` the algorithm doesn't work at all -- if you were getting poor results then you probably had an implementation bug somewhere.

Comment: @Bruce: Specifically, did you try to increase the 'window size' like I did in the example? If you are only keeping track of the target number of elements in your `shortlist`, and not a broader window, that could cause a loss of accuracy.

Comment: Yep, there was a tiny bug! Thanks for all your help. Btw, I decided to use [this](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2013/06/sift3-gone-wild.html) instead of Levenshtein distance. It's much faster and is widely used too.

Comment: @Bruce: If I understand correctly, Sift3 calculates longest common substrings, which is faster, but a lot less accurate. If I type "combute", Sift3 will rank all the following words higher than 'compute': "combination", "rhombus", "combustion", "combat", "recombine", "honeycomb", "comb", "combo"... Edit distance will yield far better results than LCS, and Levenshtein is world lighter than 'real' word similarity algorithms like soundex or metaphone.

Comment: I think calculates the Longest Common *Subsequence*. Example: My list has two entries, `snapdeal` and `grabdeal`. Typing `snabdeal` returns a distance of `1` with `snapdeal`, and a distance of `2` with `grabdeal`. If it was substring, it should've returned `grabdeal` as the closest, right? I don't know why the site says Longest Common Substring.. http://imgur.com/5Y09orx